# File upload control text language in google chrome

Tags: asp.net, html, google-chrome

I have a website in English. I am having a problem with the text of file upload control. I want to show its text in English to all users. But in chrome it shows message as per user's locale. If user's browser is set to display Google Chrome in danish it will show file upload text in danish.
Note: I know it is a stupid question as user has told chrome to show him in danish. But curious if there is any way. Because my all other page content is in English.[image: Here you can see a label with text "Browse file" followed by file upload control.]

Comment: Is Google Chrome translating your English by any chance?

Comment: @m.edmondson No, google chrome is not translating my english. I have updated the question with image for clearifying it.

Comment: Have you set language in your HTML document tag? eg. `<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Comment: @Dan Diplo Yes I have checked that by setting the language to en but not avail.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the way to fix this is to modify the `URL`, either by switching the `&hl=da` parameter to `&hl=en` or by adding `&hl=en` if it does not exist there already.

See this: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/thread?tid=6e11e4f94a9c384c&hl=en